# Royalties from Europe, but live in U.S

Tags: international, royalties

My wife lives in the U.S., is both a U.S. and Spanish citizen, and is slated to receive a small amount of royalties (about 200 euros) from a publisher located in Spain.

She has a bank account in Spain as well as one in the U.S.

What is the easiest and most correct way to receive this money? Does the publisher need to withhold Spanish taxes from the royalties? Would it be better to have it sent to the Spanish bank or to the American bank?